# How to make an If inline using ERB template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to make a simple `if...else` statement in my template.
Here is the solution I have currently:

```
<%if @collections.size > 1 %>
 coleções
<% else %>
  coleção
<% end %>
```

It is ugly I guess.

So I tried the following:

```
<% @collections.size > 1 ? 'coleções' : 'coleção' %>
```

But it didn't work.

How can I make this `if...else` statement work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You missed the equal sign `=`. You need it if you want to render something.

```
<%= @collections.size > 1 ? 'coleções' : 'coleção' %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking about your syntax, but please use the [text helper built in to Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) rather than writing `if...else` statements.

`<%= pluralize(@collections, 'coleção') %>`

Of course, Rails supports English inflections by default, but [you can add support for other languages](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#inflection-rules-for-other-locales). And [here's a gist that adds Portuguese inflections](https://gist.github.com/mateusg/924574).

Comment: Why I shouldnt use if/else in this case ?